# How to filter List of models based on a specific property value?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model `ListItem` and a method `GetAllListItems` that returns a list of all ListItems. I only want to return ListItems that with columns that match a certain criteria.

If I only wanted to return ListItems where `large = true`, how could I modify my code?

```
    public List<ListItem> GetAllListItems()
    {
        return syncconn.Table<ListItem>().ToList();
    }
```

ListItem model:

```
namespace Myapp.Models
{
    [Table("list_items")]
    public class ListItem
    {
        ...
        public bool Large { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Linq` after the fact

```
public List<ListItem> GetAllListItems()
{
    return syncconn.Table<ListItem>()
                   Where.(c => c.Table) // Where table == True
                   .ToList()
}
```

or you assuming you are using SqlLite.Net and the table name is right i believe you can do this

```
return syncconn.Query<ListItem>("select * from ListItems where Table = 1")
```